# postfix: block mails to a specific and non existent mail address

Tags: email, blocking, spam-prevention, postfix

How could I block mail to an incoming address that spammers are hammering via postfix? I have a webmin interface to postfix, so if this can be done via webmin interface that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What for? If the address doesn't exist, there is no problem to solve. Postfix simply rejects the mail and everything is fine.